# How do I add an external javascript library to Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, selectize.js

I want to add (https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ to my Rails Webpack application.

I have done the following:

- Run: `npm install selectize --save` from terminal.
- Gone to my pack's index.js and imported it with: `import 'selectize/dist/js/selectize';`

And When I open the compiled application.js I can search for "selectize" - but when I try this in my javascript (or via console):

`$('#list').selectize({
  delimiter: ','
});`

It tells me `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function`.

I know that I had to add some stuff to config/webpack/environment.js to get jQuery working, do I have to do something to get this library working?  If so, what have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

use jquery as plugin in webpack to automatically.[Here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/?_sm_au_=iVV4R8Hp0mHVVpn5) you will find the documentation.
you have to make some changes in webpack.config.js file.

```
plugins: [
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({$: 'jquery',jQuery: 'jquery'})]
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm i jquery` and you can import and try with this hope this help for u.

```
import jquery from "jquery";

new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: jquery,
  jQuery: jquery
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Github issue addresses your question: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/1421. This is a problem with the selectize library breaking when imported through webpack. A temporary solution for this is to just manually import the library.